# Android LVL (GPlay licensing): always returns error 291 on first call of doCheck

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, android-lvl

I implement Google Play LVL (Licensing library) in order to guarantee the safety of my paid app.

My problem is that when the app is launched for the first time, I get systematically error 291 (Error_Contacting_Server). I have to launch doCheck a second time to get the proper ok response (after 5 seconds, very slow).

Do you have this systematic 291 error on the first call of doCheck on first launch ?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question.

I might be wrong but I have the feeling that the LVL server is very slow and buggy when used in debug mode, that is to say when I install the app on my device directly with Android Studio and test the LVL implementation by changing the response in the Google Play Console. Indeed, it is in this case the sandbox servers which are used, not the Google Play production servers.

So, to have quick and proper responses for the LVL implementation, I upload a test apk (with toasts to see the LVL responses) to the Google Play Console in beta test channel. Then, I download the apk from Google Play thanks to the Google Play beta test URL. The LVL responses are much faster and reliable.

Please tell me if you confirm this observation.